# How can I change the AM/PM display to be in Spanish (Mexico) in a Xamarin Forms TimePicker?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, timepicker, globalization

I have a TimePicker in my Xamarin.Forms application which displays the time, but shows AM and PM using capitalized format. I believe in es-mx globalization, this should appear as "a.m." and "p.m.". I am attempting to set every possible localization value in code that I can think of to force the application into Spanish (Mexico):

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(NSArray.FromStrings("es"), new NSString("AppleLanguages"));
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
var ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ci;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = ci;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = ci;
```

I also register my languages in the info.plist as shown here:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>es</string>
</array>
```

By doing this, I do see "a.m." when I open the picker and I have the spinners at the bottom of the screen, but the time still shows with capital AM:

[image]

I am using Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.2515.

Is my only solution to use a renderer to force the text in the picker to be localized? Is this a known bug in Xamarin.Forms? Am I doing something wrong or missing some localization setting which is making this behave incorrectly?

Comment: Its not the issue with Picker having capital AM/PM, you need to handle that while displaying text on picker using Binding variables. Like YOURSELECTEDDATE.ToString(YOURDATEFORMAT);